# Application of Banach Fixed Point Theorem to sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I have the following question

Show that there is unique real bounded sequence $(a_n: n \in \mathbb{N})$ such that
$$a_n = \frac{n+1}{n}+\sum^\infty_{m=1}\frac{\sqrt{3a^2_{m+n}+1}}{4m^2}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know I need to use the Contraction/Fixed Point Theorem, so I first defined $\Phi : l_{\infty}(\mathbb{N}) \to l_{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ by

$$\Phi(a)_n=\frac{n+1}{n}+\sum^\infty_{m=1}\frac{\sqrt{3a^2_{m+n}+1}}{4m^2}$$ where $a\in l_{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But I got stuck in my attempt to show $\Phi$ is a contraction. My last line of work is

$$|\Phi(a)_n - \Phi(b)_n| \leq \cdots \leq \left|3 \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{a^2_{n+m}-b^2_{n+m}}{4m^2\left(\sqrt{3a^2 _{n+m}+1}+\sqrt{3b^2_{n+m}+1}\right)}\right|$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: You have $a_{n+m}^2 - b_{n+m}^2 = (a_{m+n} + b_{n+m}) (a_{n+m} - b_{n+m})$. The term $a_{n+m} - b_{n+m}$ is the one you want to keep, while $a_{n+m} + b_{n+m}$ is a really bad term as it can be as big as possible. Try to get rid of it using the term at the bottom. Also see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fn%5E2+%5Ctimes+%5Csqrt+3+%2F4)

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks, I had thought about using the difference of two squares, but hadn't thought enough about trying to cancel with the term at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to finalize John Ma's idea.

Note the sequence of inequalities
$$
\begin{align}
|\Phi(a)_n - \Phi(b)_n| 
&\leq \left|3 \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{a^2_{n+m}-b^2_{n+m}}{4m^2\left(\sqrt{3a^2 _{n+m}+1}+\sqrt{3b^2_{n+m}+1}\right)}\right|\\
&\leq \left|3 \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{a^2_{n+m}-b^2_{n+m}}{4m^2\left(\sqrt{3a^2 _{n+m}}+\sqrt{3b^2_{n+m}}\right)}\right|\\
&\leq \left|3 \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{(a^2_{n+m}-b^2_{n+m})}{4m^2\sqrt{3}(|a_{n+m}|+|b_{n+m}|)}\right|\\
&\leq \left| \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4m^2}(|a_{n+m}|-|b_{n+m}|)\right|\\
&\leq \sup_m|a_{n+m}-b_{n+m}|\sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4m^2}\\
&\leq \frac{\pi^2\sqrt{3}}{24}\sup_m|a_{n+m}-b_{n+m}| \\
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\Vert \Phi(a) - \Phi(b)\Vert
\leq\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{3}}{24}\sup_n\sup_m|a_{n+m}-b_{n+m}|
\leq\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{3}}{24}\Vert a-b\Vert
$$
Since $\alpha=\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{3}}{24}<1$ we may apply Banach fixed point theorem.